# How to format a number to Fixed length, space padded, thousand separator, 2 decimals in Java

Tags: java, formatting, decimal, string-formatting, padding

How to format a number into a fixed-length, space padded on left string with space as thousand seperator with 2 decimal places in Java?
(let's say 14 characters string)

I.e.

```
Number = 10.03 must be:     "         10.03" 
and  
Number = 1235353.93 must be "  1 235 353.93".
```

Answer (score 19):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00", symbols);

System.out.format("%14s\n", format.format(1235353.93));
System.out.format("%14s\n", format.format(10.03));
```

The above prints below on my machine:

```
  1 235 353.93
         10.03
```

You can also use `String.format` if you want to store the result into a variable:

```
String formatted = String.format("%14s", format.format(1235353.93));

System.out.println("Formatted Number is " + formatted);
```

However, if you weren't bothered about using  (space) as the grouping separator, you could've simply done this:

```
String.format("%,14.2f", 234343.34);
```

Which would print:

```
    234,343.34
```

Comment: What about using this formatted string anywhere else? assigning it to a variable, e.g.? can you explain?

Comment: Thanks guys, the String.format("%14s", format.format(1235353.93)) was the 1 I needed. I have to print an old COBOL report from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [String#format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) - its format string should let you do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this to format currency, it's more robust to use locales:

```
Locale uslocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(uslocale).format(payment);
```